# Draw Kinetic.Shape in for-loop - var i of for-loop isn't taken properly in drawFunc()

Tags: html, for-loop, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Is it possible to use the variable `i` of a for-loop (`for(i=0; i<3; i++)`) in wich the `Kinetic.Shape` is created to set the y-value in the custom `drawFunc();`

My code of the for-loop for the dynamic shape creation looks the following:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    layer.add(new Kinetic.Shape({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        drawFunc: function(canvas){
            console.log(i); //THIS LOG ALWAYS OUTPUTS THE MAX i-VALUE (here 3)
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(10, i*30+2, 200, 30);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }));
}

stage.add(layer);
```

If i log the `i`-value in the custom `drawFunc();` the result is always `3`instead of `0, 1, 2`, and because of that the `ctx.fillRect` draws all three shapes at `y = 92`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QZtqz/2/) is a fiddle of my code with the explained behaviour.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. By adding the layers using a function the value passed to the createLayer function is saved with each Kinetic.Shape object that's created through closures.

```
function createLayer(nbr){
    layer.add(new Kinetic.Shape({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        drawFunc: function(canvas){
            console.log(nbr);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(10, nbr*30+2, 200, 30);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }));
    }


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    createLayer(i);
}
```